# Executing shell command in python with file as stdin

Tags: python, shell, pipe

In my Python code, I have

```
executable_filepath = '/home/user/executable'
input_filepath = '/home/user/file.in'
```

I want to analyze the output I would get in shell from command

```
/home/user/executable </home/user/file.in
```

I tried

```
command = executable_filepath + ' <' + input_filepath
p = subprocess.Popen([command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
output = p.stdout.read()
```

but it doesn't work. The only solution that I can think of now is creating another pipe, and copying input file through it, but there must be a simple way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from subprocess import check_output

with open("/home/user/file.in", "rb") as file:
    output = check_output(["/home/user/executable"], stdin=file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `shell=True` in the call to `Popen`. By default, `[command]` is passed directly to a system call in the `exec` family, which doesn't understand shell redirection operators.

Alternatively, you can let `Popen` connect the process to the file:

```
with open(input_filepath, 'r') as input_fh:
    p = subprocess.Popen( [executable_filepath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=input_fh)
    p.wait()
    output=p.stdout.read()
```

Comment: calling `.wait()` before `.stdout.read()` can lead to a deadlock if the subprocess generates enough output.